# bytes were returned when we access the structure member and Segmentation fault occurs when printing structure variable address

Tags: c, pointers, memory-management, segmentation-fault, structure

I created one `struct` and assigned one pointer variable to that structure. When I tried to print the address of that variable it prints correctly. After assign value to one of the member of the structure using this `pointer` structure variable, when i tried to print the address of the `pointer` variable I got *`segmentation fault`*.

```
#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct node {
char mem;
double mem2;
char mem3;
int mem4;
char mem5;
char mem6;
}NODE;
int main()
{
    NODE * m;
    printf("%u",&m);

    return 0;
}
```

I got output as 3014616488. When I assigned variable to one of the structure member,

```
#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct node {
char mem;
double mem2;
char mem3;
int mem4;
char mem5;
char mem6;
}NODE;
int main()
{
   NODE * m;
   m->mem3 = 'A';
   printf("%u",&m);

   return 0;
}
```

I got segmentation fault. When I did like this

```
#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct node {
char mem;
double mem2;
char mem3;
int mem4;
char mem5;
char mem6;
}NODE;
int main()
{
    NODE * m;
    printf("%u",&m->mem3);

    return 0;
}
```

I got 16 as output . I don't know how 16 came. It really struggling my mind. Please any one help me to get know what exactly happening. Thanks in advance

Comment: `m` is a pointer, but you never make it point anywhere. So when you dereference it (by doing `m->mem3`) you have [*undefined behavior*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior). Uninitialized local variables will have an *indeterminate* (and seemingly random) value.

Comment: Also, when printing a pointer with [`printf`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fprintf) you should use `"%p"`, otherwise you also have undefined behavior. And the pointer should really be casted to `void *` for it to be correct. Lastly, don't forget that `&m` is the pointer to the variable `m` (and have the type`NODE **`), it's not where `m` is pointing (that would be plain `m` without the address-of operator).

Comment: regarding the second version of the code:  the variable `m` is never initialized to an instance of the struct Node.   Rather an instance of a pointer to such a struct is declared.  BUT that pointer is never set to point to an instance of the struct Node.  So the statement: `m->mem3 = 'A';` is undefined behavior, where anything could happen.  Note: all three versions of the posted code have the same kind of problem, resulting in undefined behavior

Comment: when compiling, always enable the warnings, then fix those warnings.  (for `gcc`, at a minimum use: `-Wall -Wextra -Werror -Wconversion -pedantic -std=gnu11` )  Note: other compilers use different options to produce the same thing.

Comment: 3rd version of code is not undefined , it is valid one. But its in printing the start byte of the mem3 variable. I don't know why.Please explain this. @ user3629249

Comment: The third version is *also* UB, because the `->` operator dereferences the uninitialized pointer `m`. It's also a duplicate of [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53390348/440558). Is it some class you're both going to? Online or in-person? Anyway, like I told the poster of the other question, please tell your class-mates to not post the same question again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because its not allocated any memory

```
NODE * m = malloc(sizeof(NODE));

// Do stuffs

free(m);
```

So try this :

```
int main()
{
    NODE * m = malloc(sizeof(NODE));

    m->mem3 = 'A';
    printf("%u",&m->mem3);

    free(m);

    return 0;
}
```

***Notice :***

Int `c` or `c++` if you declare a `pointer`, some memory is reserved for the `pointer` (usually on the *`stack`*). How ever the pointer is not initialized, meaning that it points to the address corresponding to what was in the respective memory location last. (This is the reason that first section of `code` is worked).

Comment: Yep, good job. You can also use the dereference pointer to always provide the correct type-size, e.g. `malloc (sizeof *m);`

Comment: 3rd version of code is not undefined , it is valid one. But its in printing the start byte of the mem3 variable. I don't know why.Please explain this

Comment: @Aadhithaneswaramoorthy which 3rd version? every thing is obvious...

Comment: @ Mohammadreza Panahi 
#include <stdio.h>

    typedef struct node {
    char mem;
    double mem2;
    char mem3;
    int mem4;
    char mem5; 
    char mem6;
    }NODE;
    int main()
    {
        NODE * m;
        m->mem3 = 'A';
        printf("%u",&m->mem3);

        return 0;
     }
This produces correct output and it returning the starting byte number of mem3 16. I what some explanation how it happens

Comment: @ Mohammadreza Panahi  Please explain me the 3rd section of code which i was tried in many compiler and I got same output ,It seems it is valid one not undefined behavior.

Comment: @Aadhithaneswaramoorthy I explained it in my answer....

Comment: @ Mohammadreza Panahi , It is not returning address . It is returning the starting byte number of structure variable. If i give printf("%u",&m->mem4); , I am getting 20 as output

Comment: @Aadhithaneswaramoorthy its correct, actually `m` including `4` byte address. Probably when you assign a value to one of the members it will be exceed of `m` address And give you `segmentation fault`. So you should initialize it to allocate a memory in heap with `malloc` and work with it safely. It is not important what happening to an uninitialized pointer when you assign values to it, because it always cause `segmentation fault`. but you should always allocate them a memory.

Comment: @ Mohammadreza Panahi . Sorry to repeatedly asking this. I understand you answer but it was not exactly i asked. I just want to know why it gives 16 for mem3 and 20 for mem4 12 for mem2 etc. It was just interview question for me. So I want to understand in-depth how it produces result as 16

Comment: @Aadhithaneswaramoorthy these values are absolutely random. because `m` is pointing to a section of `stack` and those section  has random valuyes in their memories.

Comment: @Aadhithaneswaramoorthy notice that when you leave a pointer uninitialized. When you print its value it give you  a random number always.

Comment: @Mohammadreza Panahi , It is not random number . mem is 0 and its starting byte is 0. mem2 is double data type so it starts from 8th byte and it left previous 7 bytes and mem3 is char data type,so it starts after mem3 that is 16th byte and its immediate next is int so mem4 starts from 20th byte .like wise its going. I want to know what is this behavior ?

Comment: any one explain this statement please  int a = (int)&((NODE *)0)->mem3;

Comment: @Aadhithaneswaramoorthy you cast `0` number to `NODE` struct Then use of `mem3` member.

Comment: @ Mohammadreza Panahi instead of returning address How it returning offset number.Please explain this

Comment: @Aadhithaneswaramoorthy Probably it return the value of `0x0000000` memory. but you shouldn't do this.

Comment: @MohammadrezaPanahi It is interview question , It want to know how it type cast to offset value

Comment: @Aadhithaneswaramoorthy I wonder how didn't you understand???? but i recommend you study about pointers. Sorry My explanations is enough!! I cant explain any more.